# Tracking status with Ruby and Graphql

Tags: ruby, graphql, backend

I'm looking for ideas on how to best track the current state of an event. I have a Graphql API with Ruby on the backend, and a web app to display the info to users.

The simplest version of what I'm looking to do is: track the current state of an IRL event. So let's say there is a festival that starts at 8 and has a new band every 30 minutes. I could allow an admin to create a schedule and go based on that, but there's a good chance of something putting things off schedule, and the whole purpose of the web app is for the users to see whats going on, exactly. I'm also wanting to add the ability to send out a push notification 10 and 5 minutes before the next "set" begins. That would be controlled by an admin just pushing a button.

I'm a front end engineer, and while I can create everything necessary for CRUD operations, I'm not sure what the best way to model the data for a situation like above.

Any thoughts or ideas on doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the first step would be to model and store the events in the database. Then we need a way to

1. Update the state with some kind of mutation
2. Sounds like you need some kind of polling or streaming capability. I'd probably recommend going with graphQL subscriptions if you're using the `graphql-ruby` library (I'm assuming you are)

Subscriptions will probably be able to handle both push notifications, and triggering client side updates when the event schedule changes.

https://graphql-ruby.org/subscriptions/subscription_classes.html#check-permissions-with-authorized